# Find a(n) with characteristic equation

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, recurrence-relations

Find a(n) with characteristic equation of recurrence: a(1)=3, a(2)=10, a(n)=6a(n-1)-3a(n-2) .

Started from equation t^2-6t+3=0 then find t1,t2 then take them in: a(n)=C*t1+ D*t2 then C and D have to find from a(1)=3 and a(2)=10 but I'm stuck here.

Comment: The correct equation is $$a_n=Ct_1^n+Dt_2^n.$$

Comment: you're right sorry wrote wrong

Comment: So are you still stuck ?

Comment: yes i found C and D but it needs some algebra to finish and I'm a little suck in algebra.

Comment: ?? If you have $C$ and $D$ you are done !

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$t^2-6t+3=0 \implies t=3 \pm \sqrt{6}$. Thus
$$a_n=C(3+\sqrt{6})^n + D(3-\sqrt{6})^n.$$
Now substitute $n=1$, to get
$$a_1=3=C(3+\sqrt{6})^{\color{red}{1}}+D(3-\sqrt{6})^{\color{red}{1}}.$$
Likewise with $n=2$ we get
$$a_2=10=C(3+\sqrt{6})^{\color{red}{2}}+D(3-\sqrt{6})^{\color{red}{2}}=C(15+6\sqrt{6})+D(15-6\sqrt{6}).$$
So now solve for $C$ and $D$ from the following set
\begin{align*}
C(3+6\sqrt{6})+D(3-6\sqrt{6})&=3\\
C(15+6\sqrt{6})+D(15-6\sqrt{6})&=10.
\end{align*}
I believe
\begin{align*}
C&=\frac{1}{12}(16-5\sqrt{6})\\
D&=\frac{1}{12}(16+5\sqrt{6})
\end{align*}

Comment: found that C=16-5sqrt6/12 and D =5sqrt6+16/12, is it correct

Comment: @MadeInKosovo Yes that is correct.

Comment: Thank you so much!